# List of possibly unfalsifiable questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

> The following questions have been identified as possibly unfalsifiable. How should we handle them?

## Instructions

1. One unfalsifiable question per answer
2. Include the question link and a short sentence describing why you think it's not falsifiable and what should we do (epic edit or delete).
3. If you think the question is improvable through a simple edit, then do it instead of putting it up here.
4. If the question needs an epic edit, post it here first.
5. If the question is not salvageable, put it here.

**Please only post questions that you do NOT want on the site**

Comment: Have you looked at the answers to [this question](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2198/how-should-unfalsifiable-claims-be-handled)? It seems your position that unfalsifiable questions are not on topic was the most supported.

Comment: @Sancho I've deleted a bunch of your answers (*sorry!!!*) because if you think that a question should be left open, it doesn't belong here - otherwise we'll end up with a million cases where we all agree!

Comment: I thought you wanted a bunch of possibly unfalsifiable questions on here. I generally only included ones where the accepted answer stated that the question was unfalsifiable. Part 2 of this question asked for "what should we do", and for many of the possibly unfalsifiable questions, I thought they should be kept open. Sorry, I didn't understand what you were asking for.

Comment: @Sancho: thanks, sorry for the confusion! If anyone thinks they should be closed, then it's worthwhile discussing them.

Comment: If a question is unfalsifiable, we can't answer it, so what's the point of keeping it?

Comment: "If a question is unfalsifiable" it still might be provable as true. Therefore it can be answered. And is not "there is no evidence for this claim" just as valid an answer as "yes" or "no"?

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski you may want to take a look at the concept of [falsifiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability) (it's not as trivial as it sounds). An unfalsifiable claim is not testable scientifically. "Proving" an unfalsifiable claim is the definition of "pseudoscience".

Answer (score 2):

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14359/can-humans-eradicate-all-known-life-on-earth

This question asks us to look into the future or at a hypothetical that has not been realized.

This question should be closed.

Comment: It's a what-if question, we should close it as not constructive.

Answer (score 1):

[Will the Affordable Care Act negatively impact radiologists in America?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15238/will-the-affordable-care-act-negatively-impact-radiologists-in-america)

This question asks us to look into the future.

This question should be closed.

Comment: This is answerable by economical modeling of the form routinely used to do economic projections.

Comment: So we can do original research here?

Comment: Or are you saying relying on somebody else's economic modeling?

Comment: The second . :)

Comment: Ah, I agree. Although, the question would then be better phrased, "*Is it predicted that* the Affordable Care Act will negatively impact radiologists in America", rather than "*will* the ACA negatively impact..."

Comment: that's why they pay you the big bucks (+2rep) for editing :)

Answer (score 0):

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15699/could-north-korea-really-build-a-working-nuke-in-a-year

This asks us to look into the future and have knowledge of North Korea's current plutonium stores and nuclear capabilities.

This question should be closed.

Comment: Borderline imo. One could make an economical argument.

Comment: That doesn't prove falsity, and the argument would likely have to be original research.

Comment: Some economist could have published a paper proving they don't have the money, thus making it non-original. E.g. "building a bomb costs 20x their GDP".

Comment: So, if it's possible that somebody *could* have published a paper asserting a negative, then the claim is falsifiable? Then, in that case, almost nothing is unfalsifiable.

Answer (score -1):

[Do minimum wage laws disproportionately harm black employment?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10182/do-minimum-wage-laws-create-employment-conditions-that-are-racially-biased-again)

It's not really clear to me how it is possible to answer this beyond a simple correlation. Also, like many of macroeconomic question, it's basically impossible to test.

Let's close it.

Comment: IMHO, You should start a discussion about closing ALL macroeconomic questions rather than singling out this one (as it doesn't seem very majorly different from the rest of the lot).